# What is the hex number at the end of a Cisco access-list?

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa

This is the output of `show access-list aclOUT` command in Cisco ASA firewall

```
access-list aclOUT line 15 extended permit icmp any host 10.255.255.1
echo-reply (hitcnt=2) 0x2ae70942
```

My questions is what is the hex number at the end of the Cisco access-list (`0x2ae70942`)?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

The hex string listed is the same string that is generated in syslog messages. It used in ASDM as easy way to reference syslog messages.